# Relationship between Vgs ang Vds

Tags: mosfet

Above is the output characteristics graph of IRFZ44N mosfet. As we can see, the output for various Vgs values are plotted. The highest two Vgs values (10v, 15v), have their Vds points halted below 10v whereas other Vgs values have their corresponding vds output going all the way above 10v. So is that means at vgs above 10v, the corresponding Vds output will be limited at that voltage range? Or else they are for some other reasons? [image]

Comment: Peak current limitation.

Comment: Plus power dissipation limits. For the 10V and 15V curves, they stop at about 150 watts and 3 volts Vds. This is equivalent to about 450 watts.

Answer (score 6):

The lines are cut off due to this spec for the part.

[image]

(From manufacturer [data sheet for IRFZ44N](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/427/91291-86372.pdf))

Comment: Which means that the line is limited only due to the pulsed drain current value and the maximum Vds value of the mosfet(55 volts) can be obtained at any of the Vgs levels and only the output current varies, right sir?

Comment: I would say peak pulse current limit since your graph is specific to 20us pulsed mode.

Answer (score 0):

These curves are limited by junction temperature  175'C  as indicated by I[nfineon datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz44npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3a9f220d) (1)  and  Vishay (a)

\$I_{DM}\$  Pulsed Drain Current = 160 A  absolute max @ 20us

Vishay Siliconix  indicate a higher rating of 200A but these should levels ought to be avoided.